# Pass Javascript var into django template filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm trying to pass Javascript variables to a django-filter, but can't make it work. The `height` and `width` values are set - I already tested that with simple `alert(height);` Javascript commands.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
  var height = $(window).height() / 4;
  var width = $(window).width();
  document.write('<img src="{{ obj.customer.headline_image|thumbnail:'+ height +'x'+ width +' }}">');
</script>
```

Does someone got an idea of how to pass that variables or got another idea of how to generate correct thumbnails at runtime? :-)

Comment: this wont work because .. at first the django will parse the file .. and when the file is displayed the values will be set right then ... 
so you need to send the two values you have though ajax .. other than that you will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Django is run on the server and Javascript is run on the client this isn't as straight forward. If you have to use a Django filter then it'll be better to use `ajax` and send the dimensions to a Django script as HTTP variables and in turn that can respond with the image's source.